# Quarkus Security : Impersonate User

Tags: quarkus

I am currently using Quarkus in combination with "quarkus-security-jpa" to realize a form based authentication. No problems here so far. I now got another requirement to enable user impersonation in my app. For example the admin can impersonate the user A to get the same access rights and see the same data. In Spring I would use the SwitchUserFilter for this feature.

Now to my question. Does Quarkus has a similar function? And if yes how can I use it? Does anybody have an idea how to realize this feature in Quarkus?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: did you try https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-security ?

Comment: @Bastian did you get your answer? It would be an interesting feature to have in quarkus-security-jpa.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `SecurityIdentityAugmentor` for this. See [this link](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#security-identity-customization) and to get the bigger picture about security in Quarkus, check [this link](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-architecture).

So do something like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@UnlessBuildProfile("prod")
public class Impersonator implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {

    @ConfigProperty(value="privileged.role")
    String roleWithPrivileges;

    @ConfigProperty(value="allowed.roles")
    List<String> allowedRoles;    


    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext context) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(build(identity));
    }

    private Supplier<SecurityIdentity> build(SecurityIdentity identity) {
        if (identity.hasRole(this.roleWithPrivileges)) {
            var builder = QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder(identity);
            this.allowedRoles.foreach(builder::addRole);

            Log.infof("Roles added for User(name=%s, roles=%s)", identity.getPrincipal().getName(), this.allowedRoles);
            return builder::build;
        } else {
            return () -> identity;
        }
    }
}
```